# Serilog.Sinks.Opentelemetry - Runtime exception when trying to configure to send logs to OpenTelemetry collector

Tags: c#, serilog, open-telemetry, grafana-loki, open-telemetry-collector

I have a class like this:

```cs
        public static IHostBuilder UseSerilog(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
        {
            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);

            return hostBuilder.UseSerilog((hostBuilderContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
            {
                // Here we configure host Serilog logger.

                loggerConfiguration
                    // Logger configuration is read from host configuration (typically, "Serilog" section in appsettings.json file).
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostBuilderContext.Configuration, new ConfigurationReaderOptions(DependencyContext.Default))
                    .Enrich.With<HostContextEnricher>()
                    .WriteTo.OpenTelemetry(options =>
                    {
                        options.ResourceAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            ["service.name"] = "test-logging-service",
                            ["index"] = 10,
                            ["flag"] = true,
                            ["value"] = 3.14
                        };

                        options.Endpoint = "http://localhost:4318/v1/logs";
                        options.Protocol = OtlpProtocol.HttpProtobuf;

                        // Prevent tracing of outbound requests from the sink
                        options.HttpMessageHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler { ActivityHeadersPropagator = null };

                        options.BatchingOptions.BatchSizeLimit = 700;
                        options.BatchingOptions.QueueLimit = 10;
                    });
            }, preserveStaticLogger: true);
        }
```

I call this from Program.cs file. Now, when I run the program, I get the following exception. The stack trace does not help much. Can someone please explain what could be the issue?

```
Exception while emitting periodic batch from Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
at Serilog.Sinks.OpenTelemetry.HttpExporter.ExportAsync(ExportLogsServiceRequest request)
at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink.OnTick()
```

Comment: Can you include your collector config? It's possible the configuration is incorrect, causing the collector to reject log batches.